# Disable prevent Default for ancor 'a' tag

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I have scroll div image like this

[image]

**HTML CODE**

```
<div class="side">
      <div class="data" id="data-1">
        <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1600247354058-a55b0f6fb720?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=750&q=80" alt="">
        <span> ID = data-1</span>
        <hr>
      </div>
      <div class="data" id="data-2">
        <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1599687350452-f60014809d2a?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60" alt="">
        <span> ID = data-2</span>
        <hr>
      </div>
      ...
   </div>
```

**CSS CODE**

```
.side{
      display: block;
      background: salmon;
      width: 350px;
      height: 100vh;
      overflow: auto;
    }
.side img{
      display: block;
      padding: 10px;
      width: 150px;
      height: 150px;
      object-fit: cover;
      object-position: center;
    }
```

every image have a unique id like `id='data-1'`

and then below that, I have a link to go to each image
**HTML CODE**

```
<div>
      <ul>
        <li>
          <a href="#data-1">Link to image id data-1</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#data-2">Link to image id data-2</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#data-3">Link to image id data-3</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#data-4">Link to image id data-4</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#data-5">Link to image id data-5</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
```

by default when I click a link I the windows page is going top.
that's what I want to avoid

and the result I want is the data is still on the top of the div scroll page, but the windows page is not going to anywhere

Comment: Since the href ilnk for `data-1` and `data-2` are valid, the page will go top. So what do you want to happen wnen you click on these links?

Comment: The data (image) is on the top of the scroll div, but the windows did not go to the top

Comment: Can you describe the problem a bit clearer please?  Your code appears to work fine https://jsfiddle.net/7e2tvhLc/ - the page does not go to the top in this fiddle, it scrolls the the image.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to prevent the default behaviour of the anchor tag then you need to bind click event to anchor tag and call event.preventDefault().

```js
$('a').click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
})
```

```css
.side{
  display: block;
  background: salmon;
  width: 350px;
  height: 100vh;
  overflow: auto;
}
.side img{
  display: block;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  object-fit: cover;
  object-position: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="side">
    <div class="data" id="data-1">
        <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1600247354058-a55b0f6fb720?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=750&q=80" alt="">
        <span> ID = data-1</span>
        <hr>
    </div>
    <div class="data" id="data-2">
        <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1599687350452-f60014809d2a?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60" alt="">
        <span> ID = data-2</span>
        <hr>
    </div>
    ...
</div>
<div>
    <ul>
        <li>
          <a href="#data-1">Link to image id data-1</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#data-2">Link to image id data-2</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#data-3">Link to image id data-3</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#data-4">Link to image id data-4</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#data-5">Link to image id data-5</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

**First Method**

> To add `return false` in **onclick()** method of button.

```
 <a href="#data-1" onclick="return false">Link to image id data-1</a>
```

```css
.side{
  display: block;
  background: salmon;
  width: 350px;
  height: 100vh;
  overflow: auto;
}
.side img{
  display: block;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  object-fit: cover;
  object-position: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="side">
  <div class="data" id="data-1">
    <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1600247354058-a55b0f6fb720?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=750&q=80" alt="">
    <span> ID = data-1</span>
    <hr>
  </div>
  <div class="data" id="data-2">
    <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1599687350452-f60014809d2a?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60" alt="">
    <span> ID = data-2</span>
    <hr>
  </div>
  ...
</div>

<div>
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a href="#data-1" onclick="return false">Link to image id data-1</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#data-2" onclick="return false">Link to image id data-2</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#data-3" onclick="return false">Link to image id data-3</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#data-4" onclick="return false">Link to image id data-4</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#data-5" onclick="return false">Link to image id data-5</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

**Second Method**

> To add `event.preventDefault()` in **onclick()** method of button.

```
 <a href="#data-1" onclick="event.preventDefault()">Link to image id data-1</a>
```

```css
.side{
  display: block;
  background: salmon;
  width: 350px;
  height: 100vh;
  overflow: auto;
}
.side img{
  display: block;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  object-fit: cover;
  object-position: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="side">
  <div class="data" id="data-1">
    <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1600247354058-a55b0f6fb720?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=750&q=80" alt="">
    <span> ID = data-1</span>
    <hr>
  </div>
  <div class="data" id="data-2">
    <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1599687350452-f60014809d2a?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60" alt="">
    <span> ID = data-2</span>
    <hr>
  </div>
  ...
</div>

<div>
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a href="#data-1" onclick="event.preventDefault()">Link to image id data-1</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#data-2" onclick="event.preventDefault()">Link to image id data-2</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#data-3" onclick="event.preventDefault()">Link to image id data-3</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#data-4" onclick="event.preventDefault()">Link to image id data-4</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#data-5" onclick="event.preventDefault()">Link to image id data-5</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

For more information about **[Preventing browser actions](https://javascript.info/default-browser-action)**.